# Is SO now the biggest programming community on the net?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, community

I was trying to think of other, bigger communities - and I haven't come up with any that are definitely bigger. Is "the hyphen site" community-oriented at all?

Admittedly it's a pretty loose community due to the very wide range of questions (compared with, say, a single-language group where all the group regulars know each other, because they're all reading the same questions) but even so...

Comment: Is Jon the leading user in the biggest programming community out there? :)

Comment: We're all doomed!

Comment: I have noticed that if I google something programming related SO comes up a lot more than it did a few months ago.

Comment: But we are not yet the largest community boasting proficiency in gender change procedures. The "hyphen site" still gets that honor.

Answer (score 5):

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) has 6,444,691 members. Do not know about their activity.

Comment: See here: http://www.codeproject.com/info/MediaKit.aspx

Comment: Thanks, was looking for something like that :)

Comment: Hmm... yes, I suspect we'd need some idea of a "minimum engagement" for this to make a lot of sense. Still interested in other responses though...

Comment: Interesting: I had no idea CodeProject was so windows-centric (99.5%)

Comment: @Joel did you know about why much adds are there?

Answer (score 3):

Size doesn't matter - it's a question of quality. And what better way to measure the quality of a community member's contribution than with SO rep? The SO community has the highest combined SO rep of any programming community on the web. Hence, SO is the highest quality programming community.

Comment: size does matter, it's a question of visibility. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Would sourceforge, codeplex, etc count?

Comment: I don't know... the project hosting bit of SF wouldn't count, IMO - that's just a lot of *separate* communities. Are there "big" discussion groups that everyone gets involved in?

Answer (score 1):

How exactly are you counting our "community"? Of the 2500+ pages of users on SO, only 50K or fewer have actually answered a question.  If asking a question qualifies one, then I would suggest that Google is in fact the largest "community" because every search would qualify.  I think that some of the same problems of counting that apply to SourceForge, CodePlex, MSDN, etc. would apply to SO -- who is a real member is not as clear cut as you might think.

Comment: Indeed... On reflection, it's incredibly difficult to really put together metrics for "a community."

Comment: It's this big "extends out arms"

Comment: Its a community if you can't hug them all at once. *hugs Ólafur Waage*